# T-SQL stored procedure: granting general user access to specific stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, scripting

I'm attempting to alter a stored procedure that needs the line added:

```
grant exec on dbo.sproc_name to exec_proc
```

I believe the admin setup the `exec_proc` as a group. I added this grant line following the final go statement.

However, whenever I do this I get two errors:

> Cannot find the object 'x', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

This is strange because when I try to call the stored procedure it says I also do not have permission now. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ended up resolving this issue but cannot say it was a direct fix. Basically the error I got (above) when altering / creating the sproc ended up being a permissions issue. My boss had to commit the line for me.